# Using Eclipse CDT under Windows with Cygwin

Tags: c++, gdb, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use Eclipse CDT with Cygwin, but I have problems with the debugger. I have done the following:
- installed Eclipse CDT
- installed Cygwin with gcc, g++ make and gdb
- added c:\cygwin\bin to PATH
- created a new Hello World application in Eclipse

Compiling went well from Eclipse. The first problem was that I had to set the executable manually in the run configuration. Having done this, I running also worked. But when I try to debug, I get the following error:

[image: error message]

When I switch to debug perspective, I can see the following:

[image: debug]

I tried different debug configurations, but I always get the same result.

Comment: Are you able to start gdb on command line and debug a program?

Comment: Yes, gdb works in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure gdb is located on *c:\cygwin\bin*. I believe executing **which gdb** on cygwin might help you do that.

Now, instead of adding this information to PATH and making it available to all your Windows applications, try adding it to your project settings inside Eclipse, like this guy did:
http://www.benjaminarai.com/benjamin_arai/index.php?display=/eclipsecygwingcc.php